# How are macro-molecules made in cells?

Tags: xenobiology, chemistry, biochemistry

In my quest to make fluorine based life, to main roadblock is my confusion on how macromolecules are made. Take phospholipids for example, it confuses me how cells can just stick a phosphate to a glycerol and connect a bunch of fatty acids into a chain.
Its a little hard for me to ask this question as it is a little vague, so this is the clearest I could make it:
How are macromolecules made in cells?

Comment: Perhaps better suited to biology stack exchange.

Comment: Just so as you are aware, there are many [specialist sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) covering the gamut from earth-sciences, religions, con-languages, psychology, medical, biology through to a writing stack. If it doesn't seem to immediately fit here, then try the others. Remember to take their tours and read their help centres as per usual.

Comment: I tried looking for a "biology stack exchange" but I couldn't find any

Comment: [biology.se] - there.

Comment: thank you, this can also give me some other info, thanks very much

Comment: Question in the title and question in the body are different. Title question is a simple biological question (akin to "how do people walk?"), while body question puts it in a very different perspective (akin to "how can people walk in zero gravity?").

Answer (score 2):

> How are macromolecules made in cells?

By other macromolecules.

For example, proteins are the "main" macromolecule that makes life happen.  These are made by a multistep process, a very simplistic model of which is below.  Each stage is enabled by multiple other macromolecules including proteins, nucleic acids and lipids.

Other macromolecules are made by different process, but they all involve multiple macromolecules coming together is just the right way to enable their synthesis from the constituent parts.

[image: Protein biosynthesis]
[Protein biosynthesis, from wikipedia's comprehensive page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_biosynthesis) with loads more details

Answer (score 2):

The [genetic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code) consists of a large number of recipes to make [proteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein). (No, it is not a recipe to make a fully-grown organism. It is just a library consisting of recipes to make proteins.)

Overlooking all the details which make the joy of molecular biology, a living cell functions as follows:

1. At any given moment, a large number of the protein recipes in the genetic code are copied to [messenger RNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messenger_RNA) molecules. Let's call these copies "work orders", because that's what they would be called in a factory.
2. Those work orders are picked up by the [ribosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome) which execute them, making the proteins encoded by the work order.
3. Some of those proteins are used for various structural purposes, but many of them, called [enzymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme) are [catalysts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalysis) which make improbable chemical reactions not only probable but actually favored.
4. The enzymes catalyze the chemical reactions which constitute the [metabolic pathways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_pathway) which produces useful molecules, degrade useless molecules, store energy into select molecules or liberate energy from said storage.

To find out how each phospholipid of interest is made, look up its metabolic pathway.

For more than this you and I would need a university course in biochemistry; it is a vast subject, and Nobel prizes are regularly awarded for elucidating parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Enzymes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueup2PTkFW8):

User65535's answer is correct, but I thought it would be good to elaborate a bit. The machines involved are generally known as enzymes, and to try and describe it simply, they are proteins (sometimes with other molecules and co-factors involved) that lower the energy to make a reaction happen. But they also bring together molecules that would otherwise be highly unlikely to come into association by themselves.

So you might, for example, want to bind a sugar to an amino acid. This reaction is possible, but it takes more energy to perform than the resulting molecule contains. Thermodynamics says you don't have reactions occur that create energy, so energy has to come from somewhere. An ATP molecule gets involved to provide the power, the enzyme brings the sugar and amino acid into contact, and the enzyme also lowers the activation energy. The final reaction has lower energy products, but having the sugar, amino acid, and the ATP coming together is very unlikely and would happen incredibly slowly. Other reactions might consume the products before they ever produced the desired end product.

So enzymes make highly unlikely and really slow chemical reactions happen easily and quickly enough to be of use for life to function.